# Philips Hue Light Controller

Tags: python, beginner

I have created a program where it contains the IP of the user and uses it to connect to a Philips Hue Bridge. I've just recently started python so I understand my code may be terrible.

```
from phue import Bridge
from tkinter import *
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.connect(("8.8.8.8", 80))
ip = s.getsockname()[0]
s.close()

b = Bridge(ip)
b.connect()


def startup():
    start = Tk()
    start.config(bg="black")
    start.geometry("1000x500")
    hue = Label(start, text="hue", font="Serif 30", fg="white", bg="black")
    hue.place(x=450, y=200)

    def on():
        start.config(bg="#e6cf00")
        hue.config(bg="#e6cf00")

        def app():
            root.destroy()
            lights = b.get_light_objects('name')
            count = 0
            for i in range(0, len(lights) - 1):
                count += 1
                for i in range(0, count):
                    light = Button(root, text=str(lights[count]))

        start.after(2000, app)
    start.after(2000, on)


root = Tk()
root.config(bg="#bfd8ff")
root.geometry("1000x500")
# Defaulting Variables
light_num = 0
action = ''  # on or off
ipc = Label(root, text="Completed Automatic Setup", font="Sans 30", fg="white", bg="#bfd8ff")
ipc.place(x=225, y=200)
root.after(5000, startup)


def light():

    b.get_api()

    b.set_light(light_num, action, True)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! It would benefit reviewers to have a bit more information about the code in the description. From [the help center page _How to ask_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask): "_You will get more insightful reviews if you not only provide your code, but also give an explanation of what it does. The more detail, the better._"